# Intergrate email with Sqlite without Android API

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to build an android application using Phonegap & SQlite. It will be an employee search application. I am aware how to build it using SQlite & JQueryM & create apk using Phonegap. But I want that i will have a dump link which will be mailed to the users in some interval clicking on which it should automatically update the database. Can anybody help me how I can achieve this without using any Android Native Api??

Comment: Can you explain bit more "i will have a dump link which will be mailed to the users in some interval clicking on which it should automatically update the database." ?

Comment: @DavidJhons well the requirement is such that every week a mail will be sent to the users which will contain a link to the updated database(new employee added or removed). Clicking on this link from the device it should automatically update the database of my app on the device. Something like the sync functionality. I have used the email integration functionality from Android API. But am totally clueless about how I can integrate it using the hybrid technologies as I mentioned. Is it at all feasible?? that is my query. I hope this helps u!